# $X\times Y$ is a banach space. What can you say about $X$ and $Y$?

Tags: functional-analysis

$X\times Y$ denotes the cartesian product of $X$ and $Y$. $X\times Y$ is a Banach space with respect to the norm 
$$||(x,y)||:=  (||x||^p + ||y||^p)^{\frac 1p}.$$
What can I say about $X$ and $Y$ where they are normed linear space ? Are they Banach spaces?

Comment: As far as I understand, you assume that $X$ and $Y$ are normed spaces (since you use the notations $\text{Norm}_X$...), and your question is, if $X$ and $Y$ are complete, assuming that $X\times Y$ is complete. That's true, of course, since if $x_i$ and $y_i$ are Cauchy sequences in $X$ and $Y$, then the convergence $(x_i,y_i)\to (x,y)$ in $X\times Y$ means exactly that $x_i\to x$ in $X$ and $y_i\to y$ in $Y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X$ and $Y$ are isometric to closed subsets of $X\times Y$ via the maps $$x\mapsto (x,0),\qquad y\mapsto (y,0)$$
Draw your conclusion about their completeness.